# Very Slow Select / Join Query for table on Itself

Tags: mysql

Newbie mysql question.

I have a table with indices which look like this;

```
    "Table" "Non_unique"    "Key_name"  "Seq_in_index"  "Column_name"   "Collation" "Cardinality"   "Sub_part"  "Packed"    "Null"  "Index_type"    "Comment"   "Index_comment"
============================================================================================
    "00005" "0" "PRIMARY"   "1" "RECORD_ID" "A" "1735423"   ""  ""  ""  "BTREE" ""  ""
```

If I try and run the following query

```
SELECT
        Record_ID as rid,
        Price, 
        Price_CHANGE_Ticks,
    /* Subselect returns only one Price_change_in_ticks from the next Record_ID which may not be in sequence */
    (SELECT Price_CHANGE_Ticks FROM 00005 WHERE Record_ID > rid ORDER BY Record_ID ASC LIMIT 1) AS next_change_ticks
       FROM 00005 order by rid
       ;
```

It runs very slowly and the explain seems to indicate there is no possible key for the primary select, which seems odd

```
"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "Extra"
==============================================================================================
"1" "PRIMARY"   "00005" "index" ""  "PRIMARY"   "4" ""  "1735423"   ""
"2" "DEPENDENT SUBQUERY"    "00005" "index" "PRIMARY"   "PRIMARY"   "4" ""  "1" "Using where"
```

Alternatively assuming all the records are consecutive I tried this join, but it is also incredibly slow;

```
Select pcur.record_ID from 00005 pcur LEFT JOIN 00005 plast ON (pcur.Record_ID = plast.Record_ID + 1);
```

Can anyone explain how and why this is so slow since as far as I can see the record_ID is the primary key, all this should be based on this and so it should be very quick?

Comment: Well, first of all, you are selecting all records in your main query (which is a full table scan, no index used) and for each record you are looking for all items that have a greater record_id and sorting that output. For low ids, it will be almost a full scan, for higher ids it will perform faster. However, can you tell us how many rows your table has and what you are actually trying to acomplish?

Comment: There are 2 order by, do you really have to use them?

Comment: The subquery scans exactly one row every time (order by using index + limit 1). The order clauses will not impact performance in this case (both use indexes for ordering).

Comment: In your mind, how could this query use an index if you don't have a single condition to fulfil? As other said, you're inspecting the entire table. Your subquery works fast, but seeing you have to go trough each record on a 1.7 mil record table - it's not a cheap operation. You have to open the table, inspect the contents, do the subquery and return all 1.7 mil records to the client. Yes, it will be slow.

Comment: @Martin - 1.7M rows.  I am trying to get a table of record_ID and in one column the Price_CHANGE_TICKS for that record_id and in another column the Price_Change_TICKS for the next record ID.

Answer (score 2):

There is no possible key because you don't have any WHERE conditions.

It is running slow because of the dependent subquery which, although fast in this case, still has to be run for each record in the result (the entire table). In MySQL dependent subqueries are very slow compared to joins.

Comment: Subquery is fast n this case, it's the main query that's slow since there are 1.7 mil records to return back to the client, after inspecting them. Still, +1 for valid answer.

Comment: Even if the main query is reasonably fast, it has to run the subquery 1.7M times. Fast * 1700000 => very slow.

Comment: Yes, and the same would happen with the JOIN. The lookup would be done 1.7 million times. It is an extra overhead but the primary query itself is so slow that it's basically irrelevant whether you use a subquery or a join. That's what I meant.

Comment: It is not irrelevant in MySQL, because JOIN's have a lot less overhead . Adding a join will make it slower but not nearly as much as a dependent subquery.

Comment: So basically, you're convinced that a subquery is slower and that it can't be as fast as a JOIN in **this particular case**. Sadly, you're completely wrong, having a JOIN instead of subquery here wouldn't do a thing to performance. A subquery can be as fast as JOIN or slower. In this case, the optimizer is smart enough to inspect exactly 1 record using a PK, as the explain says, the same would happen had there been a join. There's no need to continue this debate, the facts are clear as day.